# Firebase dynamic links not working as expected

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I create a firebase dynamic link using Rest API, like below

```
const parametersexample = {
        longDynamicLink:
          "https://karthickdltest.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/openinapp/articledetail?articleId=1234567890&apn=com.example.app&ofl=https://www.google.com/",
        suffix: {
          option: "UNGUESSABLE",
        },
      };
```

The article id passed in the URL is 1234567890

After API called I put the long URL in the site like this

```
<a href="https://karthickdltest.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/openinapp/articledetail?articleId=1234567890&apn=com.example.app&ofl=https://www.google.com/"
>Open Page:1234567890</a>
```

It is working, no problem in that, but when I put article id as 123, it is also working, don't know why

```
<a href="https://karthickdltest.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/openinapp/articledetail?articleId=123&apn=com.example.app&ofl=https://www.google.com/"
>Open Page:123</a>
```

It should not work